# Selenium tests that rely on pre-existing data, spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I have a springboot web app that I have finished coding and have some JUnit and Selenium tests. One of the selenium tests relies on a admin being pre-created in the database but obviously when I build the code there is no data in the database so the Selenium test fails.

My website has an admin-dashboard and portal and the test is to login as an admin and perform the admin functionalities but because there is no pre-existing data the selenium test cannot login.

I was thinking about adding creating a new Admin object and saving it to the DB as soon as the user visits the first page (registration page) but that is a rather bad practice to create an admin in a completely different controller to the admin controller?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Is it bad practice to create an admin as soon as the server starts from the 'registration' controller just so the selenium tests work?

Answer (score 0):

you are taking about end to end testing and you have stage server you simply can add test admin user to stage database and perform your test cases on it if it is fine then go production simply ...